# System of quadratic Diophantine equations $x^2-xy+y^2=a^2$,$x^2-xz+z^2=b^2$,$y^2-yz+z^2=c^2$

Tags: diophantine-equations

If it is only one quadratic equation $x^2-xy+y^2=a^2$, we can get some integral solutions as follows.
\begin{align*} 
&\left\{  
\begin{split}  
x&=k(2mn-n^2)\\  
y&=k(m^2-n^2)\\  
a&=k(m^2-mn+n^2)\\  
\end{split}\right.  
&\quad  
\left\{  
\begin{split}  
x&=k(m^2-2mn)\\  
y&=k(2mn-n^2)\\  
a&=k(m^2-mn+n^2)\\  
\end{split}\right.\\  
\\ 
&\qquad\qquad\downarrow 
p=m-n&p=m-n\downarrow\qquad\qquad\qquad\\ 
\\ 
&\left\{  
\begin{split}  
x&=k(2np+n^2)\\  
y&=k(2np+p^2)\\  
a&=k(p^2+np+n^2)\\  
\end{split}\right.  
&\quad  
\left\{  
\begin{split}  
x&=k(p^2-n^2)\\  
y&=k(2np+n^2)\\  
a&=k(p^2+np+n^2)\\  
\end{split}\right.\\  
\end{align*}

However, I'm not sure if these are the complete solutions of Diophantine equation $x^2-xy+y^2=a^2$.

But how to solve this Diophantine equation system in integers?
\begin{align*}
\left\{
\begin{split}
\large{x^2-xy+y^2}&\large{=a^2}\\
\large{y^2-yz+z^2}&\large{=b^2}\\
\large{x^2-xz+z^2}&\large{=c^2}\\
\end{split}\right.
\end{align*}
I got some non-trivial examples:

$
\begin{align*}
\left\{
\begin{split}
x&=\phantom{0}7\\
y&=15\\
z&=40\\
a&=13\\
b&=35\\
c&=37
\end{split}\right.
\end{align*}$,$\begin{align*}
\left\{
\begin{split}
x&=\phantom{0}21\\
y&=\phantom{0}56\\
z&=120\\
a&=\phantom{0}49\\
b&=104\\
c&=111
\end{split}\right.
\end{align*}$,$\begin{align*}
\left\{
\begin{split}
x&=\phantom{0}77\\
y&=117\\
z&=165\\
a&=103\\
b&=147\\
c&=143
\end{split}\right.
\end{align*}$.

https://benvitalenum3ers.wordpress.com/2016/12/20/make-x2-xy-y2-x2-xz-z2-y2-yz-z2-squares-part-4/

Comment: HINT Consider symmetry  $ (x,y,z) \rightarrow \sqrt{\dfrac{xy+yz+zx}{3}}$

Comment: Another hint: costruct point $X$ and draw points $A$, $B$, $C$ such that $\angle AXB = \angle BXC = \angle CXA = 120 °$. Then sides of triangle $ABC$ are $a$, $b$ and $c$ with $X$ be a Fermat point ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat_point). Now use the property of Heronian triangle (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heronian_triangle).

Comment: emmmm~. According to your method, three equal angles should also be $60^\circ$. @DaniyarAubekerov $\dfrac{x^2+y^2-a^2}{2xy}=\dfrac{1}{2}=\cos60^\circ$

Comment: What is $x^2-xy+y^2=a^2$? an equation with 2 variables  x,y or an equation with 3 variables x,y,a?

Comment: Thank you for your remind! @miracle173 there was a clerical error.

Answer (score 1):

Dickson book (history of theory of numbers) volume 2 page 511 has solution.

$x=(n^2-1)(m^2-1)$

$y=(2n-1)(m^2-1)$

$z=(n^2-1)(2m-1)$

Where, $m=2×(2q^2-pq-qv)/(3q^2-2pv+pq-2p^2)$

$(p,q,v)=((2n-1),(n^2-1),(n^2-n+1))$

For n=3,  $(p,q,r)=(5,8,7)$

&    $m=(4/7)$

$(x,y,z)=((-264),(-165),(56))$

$(a,b,c)=(231,199,296)$